# Measure month prior to selected month in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

```
Range_Selling_Count =
VAR SelectedDateRange =
    DATESBETWEEN(
        'Calendar'[Date],
        MIN('Calendar'[Date]),
        MAX('Calendar'[Date])
    )
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Data'[Store Code]),
    FILTER(
        ALL('Data'[Store Code]),
        CALCULATE(
            DISTINCTCOUNT('Data'[SKU NAME NEW]),
            'Data'[SKU NAME NEW] IN {"ED 250 ML", "Sugar Free", "4 Pack"},
            'Calendar'[Date] IN SelectedDateRange
        ) >= 2
    )
)
```

Using this measure for the selected month, but I need another measure for the same period last month.

Comment: subtract a month here:
DATESBETWEEN(
        'Calendar'[Date],
        DATEADD(MIN('Calendar'[Date]),-1,MONTH)
        DATEAD(MAX('Calendar'[Date]),-1,MONTH)

Comment: What is your model ? input data ? expected data ?

Comment: do you have a month offset column in your date table?